# Django EventLog: Passing in current user

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add logging to my Django app using `EventLog`. I followed an example online but not sure how to pass in the user that makes the changes. The example shows it as `user=self.user`. Obviously this wouldn't work in my case as it doesn't refer to anything in my model

### `models.py`

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ....

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # Initial Save
            if not self.pk:
                log(user=self.user, action='ADD_CLIENT',
                    extra={'id': self.id})
            else:
                log(user=self.user, action='UPDATED_CLIENT',
                    extra={'id': self.id})

           super(Client, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The save method will only know what has been passed into it, this will normally not include the request which is where you would get the current user (request.user).

You should instead add logging in the view which is calling the save method.

```
user = request.user
```